# Obtener el código de la página ya cargada mediante Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy empezando a utilizar Ajax, y tengo una duda que no consigo solucionar.

Yo estoy utilizando una función de la api de google para generar un gráfico, y luego con el método getImageURI, imprimo la ruta de la imagen. Pues bien, esta ruta es la que quiero sacar mediante ajax en otra página, pero lo que me está pasando es que en lugar de llegarme la ruta que he impreso, me llega el código js a secas.

Este es el código:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages':['geochart'],
  // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
  // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyCBvatIme596a7vSTsiu6h9jakhY5gLnuY'
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Country', 'Usuarios'],
   ['ES-AN', 100],
    ['ES-AR', 20],
    ['ES-AS', 30],
    ['ES-CN', 40],
    ['ES-CB', 50],
    ['ES-CM', 60],
    ['ES-CL', 70],
    ['ES-CT', 80],
    ['ES-EX', 90],
    ['ES-GA', 50],
    ['ES-IB', 90],
    ['ES-RI', 80],
    ['ES-MD', 70],
    ['ES-MC', 60],
    ['ES-NC', 50],
    ['ES-PV', 40],
    ['ES-VC', 30],
   ]);

   var options = {
   'title':'Map',
   'width': 480,
   'height': 480,
   region: 'ES',
   'resolution':'provinces',
   colorAxis: {colors: ['#ffe4b3', '#ffa500']},
   backgroundColor: 'white',
   datalessRegionColor: 'white',
   defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',


   };
   var my_div = document.getElementById("mapa");
   var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('mapa'));
   google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
     my_div.innerHTML = "split_token_1"+chart.getImageURI()+"split_token_2";
   });
   chart.draw(data, options);
           
  }
</script>
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="mapa"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function showHint(str) {
                if (str.length == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                } else {
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            var url = this.responseText.split("split_token_1");
                            console.log(url[1]);
                            //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML + "<img src='resources/"+arrayFotos[i]+".png'>";
                            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = url;
                        }
                    };
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "generargrafico.html", true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
        <form>
            First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
        </form>
        <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

En lugar de recibir `split_token_1data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA... etc`

que es lo que quiero, recibo

`+chart.getImageURI()+"split_token_2";});chart.draw(data, options);}</script><div id="mapa"></div> ajaxprueba:13:29
"+chart.getImageURI()+"split_token_2"... etc`

es decir, el código antes de que se ejecute el script.